# Refresh Fragment View inside itself

Tags: android, fragment

I have a big request for any of You. I would like to create a third Fragment in my simple application. Everything works fine, no error. I would like to make the last Fragment it is: "TestFragment" when I click that button inside that Fragment I'd like to refresh its View (on click button) and load another view inside this fragment (the same fragment). Please help me do this, show how to get it. I have read in Google but can not find the solution appropriate for this application.

Here is simple code:

MAIN ACTIVITY:

```
 package com.example.viewpagerexample;

import com.example.viewpagerexample.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private MyAdapter mAdapter;
    private ViewPager mPager;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new TestFragment();
           // case 1:
             //   return new ImageFragment();
            case 1:
               return new TestFragment();
// 
            default:
                return null;
            }
        }
     }
   }
```

TEST FRAGMENT:

```
package com.example.viewpagerexample;

import com.example.viewpagerexample.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("Test", "hello");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, container, false);
       // TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detailsText);
       // textView.setText("Testing");
        return view;
    }
}
```

TEST LAYOUT:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="QUIZ IMPORTANT TAKE A LOOK AT THIS!!!!!"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="asdjiasdjasoldjasjdasjdlasjdksahfkadshfalidshfladshfladsfhlasdfgjl;adkglkafdgnklfdsgjpfasmga.dsnvlkasdnvkldsnflkdasjflkasdnvlkadjvodsijfosdjv;lasdvlasdjvladosijao" />
```

DETAILS FRAGMENT:

```
package com.example.viewpagerexample;

import com.example.viewpagerexample.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Details extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e("Test", "hello");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.detailsText);
        textView.setText("Testing");
        return view;
    }
}
```

ACTIVITY_MAIN LAYOUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

DETAILS LYOUT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

How to do this refresh inside the same fragment?

Comment: Check out this link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953502/how-do-i-change-the-view-inside-a-fragment